# Predicate Calculus - Find an interpretation that makes the set of formulas satisfiable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Set consists of the following formulas.

- ∃xA(x) ∧ ∃xB(x)
- ¬∃x( A(x) ∧ B(x) )
- ∀x¬R(x,x)
- ∀x∀y( R(x,y) → R(y,x) )
- ∀x( A(x) → ∃y( B(y)∧ R(x,y) ) )
- ∀x( B(x) → ∃y( B(y)∧ R(x,y) ) )

The question is asking if the set of formulas in the language of predicate calculus is satisfiable.

One solution for interpretation has been provided so that the set is satisfiable.

However, I am wondering if there is any tip or guideline for this type of problem. From the set, I can see the symmetric property of $R$.

$$(∀x∀y( R(x,y) → R(y,x) ))$$

Other than that, it is like finding a needle in a haystack.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Start with the first bullet: it says $A$ and $B$ represent non-empty sets. Then the second bullet says that they represent disjoint sets. So a good starting place seems to be guessing that $A$ is the odd numbers and $B$ is the even numbers (or vice versa). Then you need to see if you can find a relation on the integers (or counting numbers... need to be flexible as you're zeroing in) so that the rest holds. Then brainstorm: "for all even numbers there exists an odd number that is related to it", etc.

Comment: thank you! it gave me a big picture to start with.@spaceisdarkgreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - $∃xA(x) ∧ ∃xB(x)$

Two sets $A$, $B$ are non-empty. Let's start with $A(a), B(b)$ (though possibly $a=b$).

> - $¬∃x( A(x) ∧ B(x) )$

The sets are disjoint: so the start is good, and we must add $\neg A(b), \neg B(a)$ (and now we're certain $a\neq b$) .

> - $∀x~\lnot R(x,x)$

$R$ is irreflexive.

> - $∀x∀y( R(x,y) → R(y,x) )$

$R$ is symmetric, as you noted.

> - $∀x( A(x) → ∃y( B(y)∧ R(x,y) ) )$

We have $A(a), B(b)$ so let's claim that $R(b,a)$,  Symmetry says $R(a,b)$ also

> - $∀x( B(x) → ∃y( B(y)∧ R(x,y) ) )$

We have $B(b)$ but we can't say $R(b,b)$ because $R$ is irreflexive.  Also we've already affirmed $\neg B(a)$.  So we must add a new distinct literal, $c$, to our universe, and $B(c), R(b,c)$ to our facts, and of course $R(c,b), \neg A(c)$ by previous rules. Now check that $B(c)\to\exists y~(B(y)\wedge R(c,y))$ and we're done: yes $B(b), R(c,b)$ have already bee added.

So our universe is $\{a,b,c\}$ with $A=\{a\}$, $B=\{b,c\}$, $R=\{(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$

---

Another approach; top-down; start as wide as possible and narrow down.   $A$, $B$ are non-empty and disjoint, such as odd and even (natural)numbers.   $R$ is irreflexive and symmetric, such as the $\neq$ comparison --everything is related to everything but itself.   For every odd number, there exists an even number which it does not equal $\checkmark$ so we don't have to change a thing.  For every even number, there exists an even number which it does not equal $\checkmark$ so we don't have to change a thing.   That'll do.

Comment: thank you for the answer! It certainly helped.

Comment: actual solution is quite same as yours. It would have been better if the solution provided how to deduce the relationship of sets from each formula.